# how to return 0 if no rows

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i have the 'CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE' in below query return zero when there are no rows returned.
The TARGET_NAME, TARGET_TYPE would remain the same i.e whatever is returned in the query.

```
select  TARGET_NAME, TARGET_TYPE,SUBSTR(KEY_VALUE, instr(KEY_VALUE, '.', -1, 1) + 1) as CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE 
from DBTABLE  
where METRIC_NAME = 'PARAMETER_VALUES' 
and VALUE like 'cluster_database_instances' 
and TARGET_NAME like '%ORACLE12%'
```

Please suggest.Thanks.

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the exact output you want for the "zero" case.

Comment: if you dont have any records and you wish to show 0 against CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE what are the values you need against TARGET_NAME, TARGET_TYPE

Comment: The Sample output you provided does not support your question "How can i have the 'CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE' in below query return zero" ?? Show us the example with that zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only expecting one row, you can use aggregation.  The following returns `NULL` in all columns:

```
select MAX(TARGET_NAME), MAX(TARGET_TYPE),
       MAX(SUBSTR(KEY_VALUE, instr(KEY_VALUE, '.', -1, 1) + 1)) as CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE 
from DBTABLE  
where METRIC_NAME = 'PARAMETER_VALUES' and
      VALUE like 'cluster_database_instances' and
      TARGET_NAME like '%ORACLE12%';
```

You can use `COALESCE()` to convert to whatever value you want.

If you might get multiple rows, you can use a CTE and union all:

```
with cte as (
      select TARGET_NAME, TARGET_TYPE,
             SUBSTR(KEY_VALUE, instr(KEY_VALUE, '.', -1, 1) + 1) as CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE 
      from DBTABLE  
      where METRIC_NAME = 'PARAMETER_VALUES' and
            VALUE like 'cluster_database_instances' and
            TARGET_NAME like '%ORACLE12%'
     )
select *
from cte
union all
select '', '', ''   -- replace with the values you really want
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from cte);
```

Comment: And how does this show up 0 against CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUES for empty rows?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph I beleive the comment in the code explain's it..."-- replace with the values you really want"

Comment: Yep, i saw that :-) the op wanted it to be shown up as 0

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph yes but also OP does not say what values should there be for other columns...

Comment: exactly; which is why in my answer i have put the value of 0 against the CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUES and empty strings against the other two columns

Comment: You believe that will be the problem for the OP if the answer is correct ?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . This uses `''` (which is equivalent to `NULL` in Oracle) because the columns are clearly strings.  However, the OP is asking for a numeric value.  I find that really confusing and simply decided to avoid the issue in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying SUBSTR and INSTR to a field, so if the field is null, you will get null. If you want to replace it for 0, then use NVL

```
select  TARGET_NAME, TARGET_TYPE,SUBSTR(KEY_VALUE, instr(KEY_VALUE, '.', -1, 1) + 1) 1),0) as CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE 
from DBTABLE  
where METRIC_NAME = 'PARAMETER_VALUES' 
and VALUE like 'cluster_database_instances' 
and TARGET_NAME like '%ORACLE12%'
```

Example

```
SQL> select substr('A',instr('A',-1,1) ) from dual ;

S
-
A

SQL> select substr(null,instr(null,-1,1) ) from dual ;

S
-


SQL> select nvl(substr(null,instr(null,-1,1) ),0) from dual ;

NVL(SUBSTR(NULL,INSTR(NULL,-1,1)),0)
------------------------------------
                                   0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to have a union all which checks for the existence of a record that do not match the WHERE clauses and return 0 against the CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE as below.

```
 select TARGET_NAME
       ,TARGET_TYPE
       ,SUBSTR(KEY_VALUE, instr(KEY_VALUE, '.', -1, 1) + 1) as CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE 
  from DBTABLE  
 where METRIC_NAME = 'PARAMETER_VALUES' 
   and VALUE like 'cluster_database_instances' 
   and TARGET_NAME like '%ORACLE12%'
union all
SELECT '' as TARGET_NAME
       ,'' as TARGET_TYPE
       ,0
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (select null      
                     from DBTABLE  
                    where METRIC_NAME = 'PARAMETER_VALUES' 
                      and VALUE like 'cluster_database_instances')
   and TARGET_NAME like '%ORACLE12%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `union all` with a query that returns the default you want when no rows in your query are returned:

```
select
  TARGET_NAME,
  TARGET_TYPE,
  SUBSTR(KEY_VALUE, instr(KEY_VALUE, '.', -1, 1) + 1) as CLUSTER_INSTANCES_VALUE
from DBTABLE
where METRIC_NAME = 'PARAMETER_VALUES' 
and VALUE like 'cluster_database_instances'
and TARGET_NAME like '%ORACLE12%'
union all
select null, null, 0
from dual
where not exists (
    select *
    from DBTABLE
    where METRIC_NAME = 'PARAMETER_VALUES' 
    and VALUE like 'cluster_database_instances'
    and TARGET_NAME like '%ORACLE12%'
)
```

Note: Other improvements left out to focus the task at hand.